# Can anyone translate this picture for me?

Tags: translation

I've been looking for an item for a few days now and finally found a picture of it with a label but haven't been able to translate it. This is as clear as I could get it. Any help would be appreciated, if you could translate or recognise the label. Thank you

[image: Clothing Label]

[image: Close up Logo]

Comment: can't see the first character clearly, please post a clear picture

Comment: I've re-enhanced it best I could. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How about a link?

Comment: The best I can do now is 「寶字號」